# Jenkins NodeJS Plugin fails during install phase with npm ci

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I'm trying to build a npm project ( Angular Project ) on the Jenkins master ( on a Docker ).

Last week I've setup the project and everything worked just fine. Today morning I've made a change on a branch and it kept failing during the first phase which include a node command called with the NodeJS plugin. There's no log on Jenkins so I can't really know what's going on.

Here's the stage code:

```
stages {
stage('Install') {
  steps {
    script {
      lastRunningStage="Install"
    }
    nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'node14.16', configId: '320662bf-2907-4c12-87f1-225abaa8d503') {
      sh 'npm ci'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, what change did you make? Did you change the dependencies? Is the lock file up-to-date with the package file?

Comment: I've changed the sonar.project.properties file in order to execute sonar-scanner on Jenkins. Other than that I haven't changed anything.

Comment: I've also tried to run npm i instead of npm ci but it still fails.